# Cual es la diferencia entre usar Autofact o el Host genérico de Net, que aportes trae al ponerlos juntos

Tags: c#, .net, inyeccion-de-dependencias, .net-6.0

Estoy trabajando en proyecto de Microservicios el cual tiene configurado Autofact dentro del Host genérico de la aplicación web api `builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());`

El proyecto usa los contenedores de **Autofact** para almacenar las dependencias de **MediatR** y **Pipelines**, también usa contendores de **Autofact** para almacenar referencias a los repositorios definidos en la Capa de infraestructura.

La arquitectura del proyecto esta basada de DDD, y usa el patrón de segregación de responsabilidad de consultas y comandos CQRS.

También he visto en el proyecto que utilizan el contenedor de servicios `IServiceCollection` para almacenar algunas dependencias de la capa de Aplicación como configuración del logger, swagger, u otras dependencias necesarias para la capa.

Mi pregunta es: ¿si el `IServiceCollection` también sirve como un contenedor IOC y pude manejar el ciclo de vida de las dependencias, cual es la finalidad de usar los contenedores de Autofact?

¿Qué aportes o diferencias hay al mezclar **Autofact** con el **Host** de .Net?

¿Usar los contenedores de **Autofact** es mejor que usar el `IServiceCollection` para almacenar las dependencias?

Comment: Posiblemente exista alguien en el mundo que haya ocupado todas esas librerías y te pueda responder. Seguramente si vas al sitio de Autofact te dirán que es la octava maravilla del mundo. En lo personal, llevo bastantes años de desarrollo en .net, proyectos de todo tipo y tamaño, y nunca he necesitado estas herramientas de terceros que son funcionales al desarrollo. Y al contrario, he visto muchos desarrolladores buceando en la documentación de estas herramientas, para hacer algo que .net ya lo hace y lo hace fácil.